# SmartGWT listgrid very slow while scrolling

Tags: performance, smartgwt, listgrid

I am writing a very simple SmartGWT application that populates a listgrid with 100 elements locally (no RPC or any server interaction involved).

When I scroll the listgrid, the scroll speed is noticeably slow

Environment:
SmartGWT 3.0
GWT 2.4.0

The code is as below:

```
public class RemoteFileBrowser implements EntryPoint {

// /**
// * The message displayed to the user when the server cannot be reached or
// * returns an error.
// */
// private static final String SERVER_ERROR = "An error occurred while "
// + "attempting to contact the server. Please check your network "
// + "connection and try again.";
//
// /**
// * Create a remote service proxy to talk to the server-side Greeting
// service.
// */
// private final RemoteFileServiceAsync greetingService = GWT
// .create(RemoteFileService.class);

/**
 * This is the entry point method.
 */
public void onModuleLoad() {
////            SC.say("Welcome to remote file browser!");
//      RemoteFileDialog rfDialog = new RemoteFileDialog("*.*, *.htm, *.cpp, *.hpp");
//      rfDialog.show();
        getListView().draw();

    }

    private ListGrid getListView() {

        ListGrid grid = new ListGrid();
        grid.setWidth(500);
        grid.setHeight(400);
        grid.setLeft(100);
        grid.setTop(100);

        ListGridField field1 = new ListGridField("name");
        ListGridField field2 = new ListGridField("designation");
        grid.setFields(field1, field2);

        ListGridRecord[] records = new ListGridRecord[100];
        for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
            //ListGridRecord record = new ListGridRecord();
            records[i] = new ListGridRecord();
            GWT.log("Iteraton:" + i);
            records[i].setAttribute("name", "name" + i);
            records[i].setAttribute("designation", "designation" + i);
        }
        grid.setData(records);
        return grid;
    }

}
```

The showcase examples seem to work fine.  The problem happens when I locally populate a list grid, without setting a data source.

Any ideas, where I am getting this wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help.

regards,
RV

Comment: Which browser are you using? I tested with latest Chrome (although I compiled your code with SmartGwt 2.5 version) and I had a very smooth scrolling experience!

Comment: Hi gpapaz, 
I am using Firefox 7.0.1 on Ubuntu 11.10- 64bit.  I could reproduce this issue on 2 PC's both running ubuntu and firefox 7.0.1.  

I will try using smartGWT 2.5 and see the behavior.

Comment: Tried with SmartGWT2.5, but same behavior.  To be more precise, I use the scrolling on the displayed grid using mouse scroll wheel.  If I scroll down [or up], with 2 or 3 strokes, it really takes about 3 seconds to update the view with new scrolled items.

If I scroll up and down alternately, it gets almost screwed up (like hang'ed).

After some R&D, I found that adding the below line improves it drastically, though still not very perfect.


    fileGrid.setShowAllRecords(true);

Comment: Can you test it with Chrome browser. I want to rule out the possibility of slow JS engine. The setShowAllRecords renders all records and thus lowers the time to display new cells as you scroll. Will be bad option if your ListGrid has a lot of records.